# Deploy Express server and React JS using nginx on Digitalocean

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, web-deployment, digital-ocean

it's my first time deploying Expressjs and Reactjs using Nginx on DO.  I was able to setup the frontend to be accessed from internet but I'm having trouble with the backend.  I've looked at multiple SO questions, videos, guides and still struggling for a week now.  Hope to get some insights!  Much appreciated.

Link to test site: [www.simpletodo.xyz](https://www.simpletodo.xyz)

Link to the guide I mainly follow: https://gist.github.com/sjosephrw/5bc7efbf4c332070165c61dba253288d

**App.js (relevant bit)**

```
<button
    onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        fetch('https://www.simpletodo.xyz/backend/test')
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((res) => setTest(res))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }}>
    Test Backend
</button>
{test && <div>{test.text}</div>}
```

**server.js (node/express)**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 4000;
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    console.log('is it gonna work??')
    res.json({ text: 'Broooo it works!!!!' });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/simpletodo.xyz.conf**

```
server{
        #Path to React front end
        root /var/www/html/simpletodo.xyz;

        #Main html file
        index index.html;

        #Server name
        server_name simpletodo.xyz www.simpletodo.xyz;

        #Store access log files
        access_log /var/log/nginx/simpletodo.xyz.access.log;

        #Store error log
        error_log /var/log/nginx/simpletodo.xyz.error.log;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /backend/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/simpletodo.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/simpletodo.xyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server{
    if ($host = www.simpletodo.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = simpletodo.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name simpletodo.xyz www.simpletodo.xyz;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Both frontend and backend are running using pm2

Netstat output shows backend is running on port 4000
[image: netstat]

/var/log/nginx/log
[image: log]

Comment: What are you proxying the front-end too? What's running on port 3000? Why the mix of `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`? You typically just build your React app and serve it as static files. See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/